# not able to remove color from div on a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 div :

> On clicking on "A" first div gets highlighted,
>
> On clicking on "C" third div gets highlighted,
>
> On clicking on "B" first and second div gets highlighted

However i want that

> if user clicks on "A" again, first div's highlight goes away
>
> if user clicks on "C" again, third div's highlight goes away
>
> if user clicks on "B" again, first and second div's highlight goes away

```
<div class="d-rec">A</div>
<div class="c-rec" >B</div>
<div class="l-rec" >C</div>

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.d-rec').click(function(e) {  
    $('.d-rec') .css({'border-top': '2px solid #39cd90','color': '#39cd90','padding-top': '0px'});
    });
     $('.c-rec').click(function(e) {  
    $('.d-rec') .css({'border-top': '2px solid #39cd90','color': '#39cd90','padding-top': '0px'});
    $('.c-rec') .css({'border-top': '2px solid #39cd90','color': '#39cd90','padding-top': '0px'});
    });
      $('.l-rec').click(function(e) {  
    $('.l-rec') .css({'border-top': '2px solid #39cd90','color': '#39cd90','padding-top': '0px'});

    });
});
```

[Here is a complete code](https://jsfiddle.net/lakshmipriya001/qwgb29pL/2/)

Can anyone please tell how to achieve the goal

Comment: on elem.click add a class to the element $(this).addClass('actived'), and check if elem.hasClass('actived') when users clicked. You gonna know if is actived id a second click, if not is a first click

Comment: You should use different `id` too.

Comment: yes have different id for div and toggle class name on click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you needed. You can simply achieve this using `toggleClass()` method and by moving your css code in a css file and by using simple logic as below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.d-rec,.l-rec').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
  });

  $('.c-rec').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('highlight'))
      $('.d-rec').removeClass('highlight');
    else
      $('.d-rec').addClass('highlight');
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
  });

});
```

```css
.l-rec {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 11.2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6a7c94;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 34.2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.d-rec {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 11.2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6a7c94;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 34.2px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.c-rec {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 11.2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6a7c94;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 34.2px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.dash-margin {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.highlight {
  border-top: 2px solid #39cd90;
  color: rgb(57, 205, 144);
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="d-rec">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="c-rec">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="l-rec">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all: ID's should be unique. You have three divs with the same ID, which makes it not-unique, therefore, we change your HTML to this:

```
<div class="rec" id="d-rec">A</div>
<div class="rec" id="c-rec">B</div>
<div class="rec" id="l-rec">C</div>
```

And with a few lines of jQuery, you can toggle a highlight-class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.rec').click(function(e) {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        $this.toggleClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

And define your CSS in the highlight-class:

```
.highlight {
    border-top: 2px solid #39cd90;
    color: #39cd90;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I was working on the same answer. [Here's some working code](https://jsfiddle.net/d1eaeyx7/).

Comment: @rblarsen thanks it seems to solve my problem but has stopped my previous feature that was there. On selecting second div, the 1st and 2nd div gets highlighted, which is not happening now

Comment: @lakshmipriya use classes to select multiple items at the same time, and ID's for individual elements. This answer is the perfect solution, sounds like you have simular syntax issues elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dash-margin>div').click(function(e) {
    $('.dash-margin>div').css({
      'border-top': '0px solid #39cd90',
      'color': '#6a7c94',
      'padding-top': '2px'
    });
    if ($(this).hasClass('c-rec')) {
      $('.d-rec').css({
        'border-top': '2px solid #39cd90',
        'color': '#39cd90',
        'padding-top': '0px'
      });
    }
    $(this).css({
      'border-top': '2px solid #39cd90',
      'color': '#39cd90',
      'padding-top': '0px'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.l-rec {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 11.2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6a7c94;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 34.2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.d-rec {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 11.2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6a7c94;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 34.2px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.c-rec {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 11.2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6a7c94;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 34.2px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.dash-margin {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="d-rec" id="rec">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="c-rec" id="rec">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="l-rec" id="rec">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Things To Lookout:
>
> 1, `id="rec"` same ID has been used in 3 div it's a bad syntax and not
>   allowed in HTML
>
> 2, Always use class for stying UI it's better and less messy.

I am following your method considering that maybe *you don't have control over the `CSS` file*

Hope this was helpfull for you.

Comment: It is very close to what i require but i need multiple selection, right now your code is allowing me to select any 1 of the value

Answer (score 1):

> You can do like this by adding an active class and removing it.
>
> should change the ids to be unique.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dash-margin > div').click(function(e) {  
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
/*Added active class in css*/
.active {
 border-top: 2px solid rgb(57, 205, 144);
 color: rgb(57, 205, 144);
 padding-top: 0px;
}
.l-rec{

  background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 11.2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    color: #6a7c94;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    height: 34.2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  
}
.d-rec{

  background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 11.2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    color: #6a7c94;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 34.2px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.c-rec{

  background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 11.2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    color: #6a7c94;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 34.2px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  
}
.dash-margin{
 margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="d-rec" id="rec">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="c-rec" id="rec2">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="l-rec" id="rec3">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a multiple selection requirement

Comment: @lakshmipriya See Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try your code in below format.Change css class name and property as per your need

```
 <div class="d-rec" id="recA">A</div>
 <div class="c-rec" id="recB">B</div>
 <div class="l-rec" id="recC">C</div>

    $('#recA').click(function(){
      $( ".d-rec" ).hasClass( "foo" )
          $('.d-rec').toggleClass("main");
    });
 $('#recB').click(function(){
          $( ".c-rec" ).hasClass( "foo" )
              $('.c-rec').toggleClass("main");
        });
 $('#recC').click(function(){
          $( ".l-rec" ).hasClass( "foo" )
              $('.l-rec').toggleClass("main");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will solve your problem in better way

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.d-rec').click(function(e) {  
  
    if($('.d-rec').hasClass('inactive')){
     $('.d-rec').removeClass('inactive');
     $('.d-rec').addClass('active');
    }else{
     $('.d-rec').removeClass('active');
      $('.d-rec').addClass('inactive');
    }
    });
     $('.c-rec').click(function(e) {  
    if($('.c-rec').hasClass('inactive')){
     $('.d-rec').removeClass('inactive');
     $('.d-rec').addClass('active');
      $('.c-rec').removeClass('inactive');
     $('.c-rec').addClass('active');
    }else{
     $('.d-rec').removeClass('active');
      $('.d-rec').addClass('inactive');
      $('.c-rec').removeClass('active');
      $('.c-rec').addClass('inactive');
    }
    });
      $('.l-rec').click(function(e) {  
    if($('.l-rec').hasClass('inactive')){
     $('.l-rec').removeClass('inactive');
     $('.l-rec').addClass('active');
    }else{
     $('.l-rec').removeClass('active');
      $('.l-rec').addClass('inactive');
    }
     
    });
});
```

```css
.l-rec{

  background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 11.2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    color: #6a7c94;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    height: 34.2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  
}
.d-rec{

  background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 11.2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    color: #6a7c94;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 34.2px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.inactive{
  border-top: 0px;
}
.active{
  border-top: 2px solid #39cd90;
  color:#39cd90
  
}
.c-rec{

  background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 11.2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    color: #6a7c94;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 34.2px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  
}
.dash-margin{
 margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="d-rec inactive" id="rec">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="c-rec inactive" id="rec">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="l-rec inactive" id="rec">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.d-rec').click(function(e) { 
   if(jQuery('#rec1').attr('style')){
    $('#rec1').removeAttr("style");
    }
    else{
    $('.d-rec') .css({'border-top': '2px solid #39cd90','color': '#39cd90','padding-top': '0px'});
    }
    
    
    });
     $('.c-rec').click(function(e) {  
    if(jQuery('#rec2').attr('style')){
    $('#rec2').removeAttr("style");
     $('#rec1').removeAttr("style");
    }
    else{
    $('.d-rec') .css({'border-top': '2px solid #39cd90','color': '#39cd90','padding-top': '0px'});
    $('.c-rec') .css({'border-top': '2px solid #39cd90','color': '#39cd90','padding-top': '0px'});
    }
    
    });
      $('.l-rec').click(function(e) {  
    if(jQuery('#rec3').attr('style')){
    $('#rec3').removeAttr("style");
    }
    else{
    $('.l-rec') .css({'border-top': '2px solid #39cd90','color': '#39cd90','padding-top': '0px'});
    }
    });
});
```

```css
.l-rec{

  background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 11.2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    color: #6a7c94;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    height: 34.2px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  
}
.d-rec{

  background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 11.2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    color: #6a7c94;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 34.2px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.c-rec{

  background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 11.2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    color: #6a7c94;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 34.2px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  
}
.dash-margin{
 margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="d-rec" id="rec1">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="c-rec" id="rec2">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 dash-margin">
    <div class="l-rec" id="rec3">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```